# Why does this ajax data parameter work on Webform but not in MVC and the other way around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was quite confused with constructing data parameter of ajax using ASP.NET MVC and Webform and need an explanation from stackoverflow community.

Passing javascript object literal as data parameter in ajax using MVC

Why does this work in MVC?

MVC Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Register(string Name, string Birthday, int Gender)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        return Json(message);
    }
```

Javascript Code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Test/Register",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {  //javascript object literal
            Name:name,
            Birthday:birthday,
            Gender:gender
        }
    }).success(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }).error(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
```

But it does work on Webforms?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/WebForm3.aspx/Submit',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            Name: name,
            Salary: salary
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

On the other hand

Passing javascript object literal as a string as data parameter in ajax does work on Webforms

Javascript Code:

```
    var name = $("#Name").val();
    var salary = $("#Salary").val();
    var data = "{ Name:'" + name + "', Salary:'" + salary + "'}"; //string
    $.ajax({
        url: '/WebForm3.aspx/Submit',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });


    Webform WebMethod

    [WebMethod]
    public static string Submit(string Name, String Salary)
    {
        return "Success";
    }
```

But doesn't work on MVC

Javascript Code:

```
    var name = $('#Name').val();
    var birthday = $('#Birthday').val();
    var gender = $('#Gender').val();
    var data = "{ Name:'" + name + "', Birthday:'" + birthday + "', Gender:'" + gender + "'}";

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Test/Register",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
    }).success(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }).error(function (response) {
        alert(response);
    });
```

MVC Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Register(string Name, string Birthday, int Gender)
    {
        .
        .
        .
        return Json(message);
    }
```

The question is.. why?

Comment: You have not set the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option in the last example (your sending stringified data and you need to set it so that the correct ValueProvider is used)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Tested it.  And it now works! Thanks a lot